# Como verificar as variáveis que não são usadas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variáveis, visual-studio-2015, warnings

Exite alguma forma de verificar quais variáveis não são usadas dentro do [escopo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escopo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) de uma classe?

Como no exemplo abaixo, as variáveis *teste1* e *teste4* não tem utilidade nenhuma dentro da aplicação, como poderia localizar tais variáveis?

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
namespace bDBContext
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        string teste1 = ""; // não usada
        bool ok = true; // usada
        string teste2 = ""; // usada

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string teste3 = teste2; // usada

            if (ok)
            {
                string teste4 = ""; // não usada
            }
        }

        public void Salvar()
        {
            string teste5 = ""; // usada
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(teste4))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Algo não tenha que usar ferramentas paga de terceiros como o *Resharper*.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes. Serve qualquer coisa no VS? Qualquer edição/versão? Pode ser outras ferramentas grátis? Pode ser algo escrito por você? Está falando dos campos da classes? Não das variáveis dos métodos? Tem um exemplo?

Comment: @bigown, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Irei ver todas as opções abaixo antes de escolher a que mais nem convêm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Versões de Entrada do Visual Studio**

Não existe nada embutido no Visual Studio (nas versões de entrada) exceto os avisos de warnings durante a compilação. Esses avisos informam as variáveis nunca usadas (note que uma variável privada que é atribuída dentro de um construtor, mas não é mais utilizada fora dele não é reportada como não utilizada, até onde sei).

Você pode dar um duplo clique em cada aviso que será levado para a linha de código onde a variável, ou método não utilizada(o) foi declarada.

O ideal é usar uma ferramenta, e a melhor é o Resharper, mas como é pago, talvez uma solução seja usar o FxCop que é gratuito: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544

**Versões Premium do Visual Studio**

Para as versões Premium e Ultimate do Visual Studio 2012, 2013 e 2015 a funcionalidade de *Static Code Analysis* foi derivada e evoluída do FxCop, portanto, se você já tem uma versão premium do Visual Studio, deve ter acesso a essas funcionalidades.

No meu Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate eu acesso a análise de código pressionando <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> ou com o botão direito do mouse como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: Selecionado Code Analysis no Visual Studio Ultimate 2012]

Na tela de execução da análise de código você provavelmente precisará configurar quais regras de análise quer usar (colocar todas é legal, mas pode ser demais). Para pegar variáveis não usadas escolhi a opção exibida na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma extensão gratuita que faz isso:[CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/)

Ela não é tao completa como o *Resharper*, mas adiciona vários atalhos que não existem nativamente no Visual Studio.

Funciona com as versões express e community.

Comment: Poderia indicar onde tem uma informação sobre isso que faz o que está na pergunta?

Answer (score 4):

Depende da configuração do compilador, mas já faz isso por padrão.

Se for campo privado o compilador pode emitir *warning*. Especialmente os [CS609](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0169?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [CS414](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0414?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) alertam sobre campos não usados, sem e com valor, respectivamente.

Campos públicos fica mais complicado porque pode ser normal na classe que ele não seja usado dentro da classe. Sobre alertar o não uso de campos internos já [foi debatido sobre](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/should-we-produce-warnings-for-unuseduninitialized-internal-fields?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Variáveis locais são alertadas com o [CS0219](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0219?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e o [CS0168](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0168?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Também é possível usar a ferramenta da Microsoft de análise de código, nesse caso seria o *warning* [CA1823](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/code-quality/ca1823-avoid-unused-private-fields?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas não vejo necessidade, ele não faz mais do que o compilador já faz para esse caso.

Tem outros *warnings* que podem verificar coisas semelhantes.

Em campos públicos é bem mais complicado fazer a verificação, há casos que nem faz sentido. Mas é possível. Esse é um dos motivos de eu não dispensar o ReSharper.

Answer (score 3):

Eu recomendaria usar o [Code Cracker](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab588981-91a5-478c-8e65-74d0ff450862).

É uma extensão para análise de código que age diretamente como um Analyzer do Roslyn. Além disso, é open-source e seu código está disponível no [GitHub](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker)

Por fim, é desenvolvida por brasileiros, e o povo que criou a extensão é bem receptivo e tranquilo pra conversar e ajudar, e bastante ativos na comunidade.